# Sphinx + Vagrant + Laravel. Connection refused

Tags: laravel, configuration, vagrant, sphinx, homestead

Sphinx on test project is work. But no local version.

- install vagrant (laravel homestead): work!
- clone project to vagrant: work!
- open ssh tunnel for mysql: work!
- sphinx: **connection refused**

sphinx.conf on vagrant = sphinx.conf on test project

Hepl me, please!

Comment: Think you will need to provide more details. No awards for writing a concise question. Not changed by the word

Comment: `$c = \DB :: connection("sphinx");$rs = $c->select("call keywords(?, 'index')", [$text]);` this code not working on local version (vagrant with ssh connection to database), error "Connection refused"

Comment: Is searchd running? Otherwise possibly a firewall?